# Jobrunr background server stopped polling

Tags: postgresql, jobrunr

I had a number of jobs scheduled but seems none of the jobs were running. On further debugging, I found that there are no available servers, and in the jobrunr_backgroundjobservers table, it seems that there has not been a heart beat for any of the servers. What would cause this issue? How would I restart a heartbeat? And how would I know when such an issue occurs and the servers go down again, given that schedules are time sensitive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will stop polling if the connection to the database was lost or the database goes down for a while.

The JobRunr Pro version adds extra features and one of them is database fault tolerance - if such an issue occurs, JobRunr Pro will go in standby and will start processing again once the connection to the database is stable again.

See https://www.jobrunr.io/en/documentation/pro/database-fault-tolerance/ for more info.